# When I use rigidbody.move rotation, my player sinks

Tags: unity, movement, rigidbody

I am trying to implement a simple movement on an object and when I use `movePosition` from rigid body, the player starts to sink:

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?
Below is my code.

```
void Update()
{
    Movement();
    MouseLook();
}

void MouseLook()
{
    //get X movement of mouse and save as float y
    //get Y movement of mouse and save as float x
    float _xMove = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensetivity * Time.deltaTime;
    float _yMove = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensetivity * Time.deltaTime;

    //make vector of that movements
    Vector3 xLook = new Vector3(_xMove, 0f, 0f);
    Vector3 yLook = new Vector3(0f, _yMove, 0f);

    //apply Y vector to body and rotate it entirely
    _rigidBody.MoveRotation(_rigidBody.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(yLook));
    //apply X vector on camera to rotate it.
    _camera.transform.Rotate(-xLook);
}
void Movement()
{
    //Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    //_charController.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * WalkSpeed);

    //register x axis movement
    //register y axis movement
    float _xWalk = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float _zWalk = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    //Make vectors
    Vector3 _WalkSum = (transform.right * _xWalk + transform.forward * _zWalk).normalized;

    //feed this to Move position of rigid body
    if (_WalkSum != Vector3.zero)
    {
        //_rigidBody.velocity=transform.forward+_WalkSum;
        //_rigidBody.AddForce(_WalkSum*WalkSpeed);
        //_rigidBody.MovePosition(_WalkSum);
        _charController.Move(_WalkSum * WalkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code by images, use the code annotation for it. It makes it harder for others to recreate your error

Comment: Sorry about that. I have done a littlebit of changes and here it is. Still not working

Comment: Try to delete the rigidBody and see if your movement does what it should. Character Controller is for bodies that don't use rigidbodies. Both together are doing funny things

Comment: Oh gosh!! This rigid body was bothering me for the past 3 hours. Now I tested other prefabs In which I removed the rigid body and it worked like a charm. Is there some way I can Use a character controller for movement and a Rigid body for other physics-related things simultaneously for

Comment: According to the docu: "On the other hand, if you want your player character to be affected by physics then you might be better off using a Rigidbody instead of the Character Controller." 
Now it depends on your game, if all the character controller is offering you is movement (and you have easy terrain), it will be easier to do the movement over rigidbody as well.

Comment: Correct! I'll learn more about it